# ViewPager starts with the first index of arrayList of images

Tags: android, gridview, arraylist, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener

I have made a view pager sliding demo,I have a gridView in that I have displayed images from arrayList of ImageURL,Now I want to display that image in next activity on its click,And then it shold slide on swipe,I have implemeted ViewPager for it,And have set adapter to viewPager,Sliding function is working fine,But when i click on any of images from GridView,It displays always the first image from the arrayList,But it should display the image which has been clicked,So Always the first position image from arrayList is diaplsyed,So What should i do for start ViewPager from the image that I have clicked,Please help and save ,Thank you have a nice day.My code is as below:

**GridActivity.java**

```
GridView gd_product;
ArrayList<String> resultArray;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subcategory);
        initialize();
        sub_cat = getIntent().getStringExtra("sub_cat");
        cat_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("cat_name");
        menu.setSelectedTab(1);
        titlesubCat.setText(cat_name);

        System.out.println(":::::::::Inside catalog:::::::::");
        new GetSubCatalogList().execute();
        gd_product.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                big_image = subCatList.get(position).get(Const.TAG_BIG_IMG);
                i = new Intent(SubCatagoryActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                i.putStringArrayListExtra("array", resultArray);
                i.putExtra(Const.TAG_BIG_IMG, big_image);
                i.putExtra("cat_name", cat_name);
                i.putExtra("pos", position);

                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

here **big_Image** is imageUrl which is clicked,And **pos** is position of that Imageurl inside the **ResultArray(ArrayList of ImageURL)**

**BigImage.java**

```
ArrayList<String> resultArray;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    public static ImageLoader imageLoader;
resultArray = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("array");
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();

        pos = getCategoryPos(big_img);
        System.out.println("::::::::::::::INDEX OF::::::::::::" + pos);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    if (isOnClick) {
                        if (event.getX() > viewPager.getWidth() / 2) {
                            // go to next

                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos, true);

                            pos++;
                        } else {
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos, true);
                            pos--;
                            // go to previous
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }); 

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultArray.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = DetailsActivity.this;
            ImageView imageView;
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            try {

                int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                        R.dimen.padding_medium);
                imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

                imageLoader.displayImage(resultArray.get(position), imageView);

                ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
    }
int getCategoryPos(String category) {
        return resultArray.indexOf(category);
    }
```

Comment: too much code and i can't get what you did. all thing that you must do, send position or sent one object to next class,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you set an adapter to your GrodView?
Have you looked [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)